# What happens at the molecular level when a spring is being extended?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, material-science, spring

To my knowledge, at the point when a spring is being extended until the bottom of it is stationary, the electrostatic forces of attraction between the molecules in the spring balance out with the external force exerted on the spring. However, when extending a spring, wouldn't the molecules in the spring simultaneously exert attractions to the end that's being extended? Thus, wouldn't this attraction balance out the applied force and keep the spring unable to be extended at all?

Comment: Very related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/146871/how-is-potential-energy-actually-stored-in-a-steel-spring-at-the-atomic-level?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Why is the restoring force directly proportional to extension?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/246604/why-is-the-restoring-force-directly-proportional-to-extension)

Comment: Hi, I don't think the answer under that question mentions why the external distorting force can be greater than the molecular attraction, which is the focus of my question.